# Create a new photo at the tapped point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a new photo at the point I touch it and I want it to be done with every touch so I wrote the following line inside the void Update () function.

```
public Canvas cv;
public Image im;
```

I have defined the UI elements above.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {   Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Instantiate(im, Input.GetTouch(i).position, Quaternion.identity).transform.SetParent(cv.transform, false);
        }
    }
```

And when I try it with the unity remote app, I take the picture about 3-4 fingers above the point I click. what's the problem? please help!

[image]

```cs
Vector2 scaleSomething()
{
    var screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPosition);
    var scaler = cv.GetComponentInParent<CanvasScaler>();
    var guiScale = 1.0f;
         if (Mathf.Approximately(scaler.matchWidthOrHeight, 0.0f))
             guiScale = scaler.referenceResolution.x / (float) Screen.width;

         else if (Mathf.Approximately(scaler.matchWidthOrHeight, 1.0f))
             guiScale = scaler.referenceResolution.y / (float) Screen.height;
         return new Vector2(
             (screenPosition.x - (Screen.width* 0.5f)) * guiScale,
             (screenPosition.y - (Screen.height* 0.5f)) * guiScale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the set parent part after instantiating

edit what is happening is when you instantiate your objects as children they get translated/scaled in local space to the parent. Because your canvas is getting stretched (scaled up on y) your children elements are also getting scaled up on y and are out of place.

Comment: I tried, but since it is not a member of the canvas, I never see the new images on the screen.

Comment: i edited my answer to explain better, you just need to calculate how much your canvas is being scaled as a percentage and reduce the percent in your child objects

Comment: sorry but ı dont understand this part  calculate how much your canvas is being scaled as a percentage and reduce the percent in your child objects. 
exactly what should i do

Comment: I understood where the error is, but it doesn't show up on the screen without the child of canvas. how can i calculate.

Comment: try canvas.scaleFactor

Comment: I added a new code fucntion on main task and canvas properties. Can u look at this? again get fail. what am i missing